# Using a array to print the result in a list

Tags: php, arrays

i just create a php file to print the result in a list using array

my code is:

```
<?php $targets = ["Test"=> array(
                      "fake1"=>"http://fakeimg.pl/$i/",
                      "fake2"=>"http://fakeimg.pl/$i/?text=Hello")
                 ]; ?>

<ul id="gallery_img">
    <?php
    $start = 100;
    $end = 200;
    for( $i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++){
        if($i <= 99 && $i >= 10){
            $target = $targets["Test"]["fake1"];
        }if($i >= 100){
            $target = $targets["Test"]["fake2"];
        }
        echo "<li><img src=\"$target\" alt=\"$i\" title=\"$i\" /></li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

the `for()` is to keep the numbers between 100 to 200, and print the img in the list, the src for the image is on the array.

i had a problem when i declare a variable `$i` in the array, i call it like this `$target = $targets["Test"]["fake2"]` the `$i` variable don't take it from the `for()` so what i done?  help me please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a few syntax errors in how the $targets array is declared.  Try this:

```
<?php $targets = array("Test"=>array(
                                        "fake1"=>"http://fakeimg.pl/",
                                        "fake2"=>"http://fakeimg.pl/?text=Hello")
                 ); ?>

<ul id="gallery_img">
    <?php
    $start = 100;
    $end = 200;
    for( $i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++){
        if($i <= 99 && $i >= 10){
            $target = $targets["Test"]["fake1"];
        }if($i >= 100){
            $target = $targets["Test"]["fake2"];
        }
        echo "<li><img src=\"$target\" alt=\"$i\" title=\"$i\" /></li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Additionally - since $start is 100, the first condition will never be met.  If you want some output with the ["fake1"] contents, set `$start = 11`

Comment: what about the variable $i in the array?? the code is about that show result in a list http://fakeimg.pl/100 , http://fakeimg.pl/101 ....

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the strings contained in the `$target` array as templates. They will not be dinamically reevaluated in your for loop or practically anywhere else. You can use `sprintf` to achieve what you desire, however:

```
<?php $targets = ["Test"=> array(
                      "fake1"=>"http://fakeimg.pl/%d/",
                      "fake2"=>"http://fakeimg.pl/%d/?text=Hello")
                 ]; ?>

<ul id="gallery_img">
    <?php
    $start = 100;
    $end = 200;
    for( $i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++){
        if($i <= 99 && $i >= 10){
            $target = sprintf($targets["Test"]["fake1"], $i);
        }if($i >= 100){
            $target = sprintf($targets["Test"]["fake2"], $i);
        }
        echo "<li><img src=\"$target\" alt=\"$i\" title=\"$i\" /></li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

In the code above, I modified the lines **2**, **3**, **12** and **14**, outlined below:

```
/* line 02 */ "fake1"=>"http://fakeimg.pl/%d/",
/* line 03 */ "fake2"=>"http://fakeimg.pl/%d/?text=Hello")
/* line 12 */ $target = sprintf($targets["Test"]["fake1"], $i);
/* line 14 */ $target = sprintf($targets["Test"]["fake2"], $i);
```

By the way, the body of the first `if` clause will never be executed. It'd be nice to review your code with care.

Comment: yeah of course the first if don't have sense but you answer my question thanks